# add API key to url

Tags: https, get

Hi I'm build a wildfire app tracker with react using the nasa API it works in development by using the url directly witch is `https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/events`

But when I deploy it. It does not get the data.  I obviously need a api key witch I have, but how do I implement it in the url above ?

here is my code..

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchEvents = async () => {
            setLoading(true)
            const res = await fetch('https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/events')
            const {events} = await res.json()

            setEventData(events)
            setLoading(false)
        }

        fetchEvents()
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a .env file in which you can set URLS as

REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL=https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/events

and then in your app component import as

```
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL)
```

Comment: Yes I tried that didi not work. What I need to know is how to embed the actual API key that I registered with on NASA, the generated key from NASA. How to implement that into the url